# Inserting an Image into a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon

I'm having an issue inserting images into a JTable.  Ive searched and found there are 2 ways.  You can either override the getcolumnclass of the tablemodel or create your custom tablecellrender.

I chose to make my own cell renderer with this code:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    /*
     * @see TableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable, Object, boolean, boolean, int, int)
     */
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                 boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                                                 int row, int column) {
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/green.png");
      setText((String)value);
      setIcon(icon);
      return this;
    }
}
```

In the method where I fill in my table's fields, I am adding the images with this line..

```
laneTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new MyRenderer());
```

The problem is that the images are showing up as blank white space.  Its definitely rendering something because when you select the row, all of the fields highlight blue except for the 4th column(the one with the images) is still white.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why the images are not showing.  I've adjusted the row height in all sorts of ways to see if maybe the image was there, but out of view or something.  Doesn't seem to be the case.

I also tried to do the override method but I guess I didn't do the syntax correctly because netbeans was giving syntax errors, and I have yet to find a decent example on how to do it.

Thanks.

edit: I've attempted the easier way, overriding the class using the code below but the cells are still blank.  And I have tested inserting images into labels and those work, so the path is correct.

```
           @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {

            if (column == 4)
            {

                return ImageIcon.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
            // other code; default to Object.class
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

> I chose to make my own cell renderer with this code..

Why reinvent the wheel? As you can see you are having problems, so just use the default renderer and override the getColumnClass() method.

Also, you would NEVER read the image in the rednering code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JFrame
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        ImageIcon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
        ImageIcon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
        ImageIcon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {aboutIcon, "About"},
            {addIcon, "Add"},
            {copyIcon, "Copy"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableIcon frame = new TableIcon();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Update:

Maybe this is easier to understand:

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
//  return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    return (column == 0) ? Icon.class : Object.class;
}
```

Comment: Oops, you are faster than me.

Comment: @Jesse:  The override is just saying to use the first cell's object's class in a given column as the class for the entire column.  Since the model value at that cell would be an `ImageIcon`, it would return `ImageIcon.class`.

Comment: Well I just tried the override method and its just displaying the pathname of my image, like its not calling the correct override.  I obviously didn't do it right.  I'm using netbean's GUI creator thing and because they are SO COOL all the code is locked out.. so i can't do it like the example

Comment: I'm obviously just not getting something here.

What do I need to do, to override the getcolumnclass, then insert an image into the row/column.  Is there an example of all the steps together?  This example has you overriding the class at creation of the table in the code.. I can't do that because netbeans locks that out, so whats the syntax to do it when im filling my table with values?

Comment: Of course you can extend and override classes and methods in Netbeans. If wouldn't be an effective tool if you couldn't. This is why you should spend time learning Java and not the IDE. I don't know what the generated code looks like to I can't suggest what you need to change or where you need to change it.

Comment: Yes, I know you can ovrride methods in netbeans.  All I want to know is the syntax to override the getcolumnclass method.  Nothing I am doing is working.

Comment: Why is this method any different than any other method you have overridden before? You where able to do it with your attempt at a custom renderer, why is it any different with a JTable?

Comment: Because netbeans auto generates the code, and you can't edit the code for the table creation.  In your above example, you override the getColumnClass when you declare your table.  Netbeans locks out that section so you can't edit it.  And in fact, I just looked.. netbeans is even overriding the method already, but its doing it as return types [columnIndex].  So basically, I have to override it again, somewhere else, somehow.