# Images are blank in JTable

Tags: java, jtable, imageicon

I'm trying to add an image to a column in a JTable but they appear blank when the columns are filled.

I am overriding the getColumnClass.  Here is the table declaration...

```
   laneTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Lane ID", "Status", "Traffic", "Gate Arm", "Lane Indicator", "Temperature"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {

            if (column == 4)
            {

                return ImageIcon.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
            // other code; default to Object.class
        }


    });
```

so obviously, column 4 is my column where images are to be displayed.  I am populating my table with..

```
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/test.jpg");
  laneTable.getModel().setValueAt(icon,i,4);
}
```

The path to my images is /src/Images/test.jpg  in case my pathname is somehow incorrect...
Ive been dealing with this for the last week and i CANNOT figure out why these images keep showing up blank in my table.

Ideas?

*edit* here is what I guess is an SSCCE.  No idea if it will work or not..

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LaneGUI extends javax.swing.JApplet implements Runnable {
    private Connection connection;
private XMLParser xmlParser;
private laneData laneData;
private SiteData siteData;
private Thread connectionThread;


public void init() {        


    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {                    
                initComponents();                  
              ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Images/test.jpg");

               for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
          laneTable.getModel().setValueAt(icon,i,4);
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}   


/** This method is called from within the init() method to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")   




// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {


    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    laneTable = new javax.swing.JTable();



    laneTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Lane ID", "Status", "Traffic", "Gate Arm", "Lane Indicator", "Temperature"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {

            if (column == 4)
            {

                return ImageIcon.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
            // other code; default to Object.class
        }


    });
    laneTable.setRowHeight(100);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(laneTable);

    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)     
            .addContainerGap())
    );

}// </editor-fold>                        







// Variables declaration - do not modify                     

private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable laneTable;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

*edit* Tested the images in a new label, the images show correctly inside a label, but are still blank inside of the table.

Comment: Not enough info to be able to see what is going on. Maybe you could create a simple example that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: if you can post an SSCCE, or at least put your getValueAt,setValueAt method implementation.

Comment: Uhh, maybe that is my issue.. This is all the code I have to implement what I want.  What am I missing?  I'm declaring an image icon, then setting that value into the table.  And I've overridden the getcolumnclass to return an image.class for columns containing image icons.  What is left?

Comment: You're missing enough code so that we can compile and run the demo ourselves. Please check out this link: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Jesse Durham first TableColumn start with zero, then on TableView is really 5th. :-)

Comment: @mKorbel - I know, the array starting at 0 isn't the issue.

Comment: that not true at all read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222951/java-put-image-in-jtable-cell, 1) remove Class[] types = new Class [] {, 2) Icon.class 3) 4th column is in TableView 5th, beacuse TableColumn/Row start with zero value, that my fast hands ignore that please

Comment: My "lane indicator" column is where I want to display my image.  Which is in fact the "5th" column in the table.  The class[]types new class[] was auto generated by netbeans for the jtable.  And I don't understand what you want me to do with Icon.class

Comment: are you read thread, that I link posted, just replace  "return ImageIcon.class;" to "return Icon.class;" :-), there no discusion about that, because I didn't know somebody who knows JTable better as camickr ...

Comment: changing to icon.class didn't do anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting an Image into a JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472658/inserting-an-image-into-a-jtable)

Comment: @trashgod bump that reason to start to check the userprofile +1

Comment: Thats cool and all but the question wasnt answered in either one of the posts (even though I think they are separate issues).  Sooo. yeah.

Comment: *"here is what I guess is an SSCCE."* `11 errors` Short answer, no.  Long answer, nope.

Comment: It IS suppose to be an applet.  Did you account for that?

Answer (score 1):

A blank image might not be a path issue but a rendering issue.  Look at your CellRenderer for that column.  Is it using the default renderer or are you doing something special.

Try just printing out the path to make sure it is getting in the cell.   Also try accessing that path from outside the `JTable` to make sure there is not a path issue at all.

Comment: Ive already tried creating my own cell renderer, it had no effect.  (although i didn't override my column then either)  The pathname of the image DOES print if i don't override the getcolumnclass

Comment: @Jesse, you should be able to use the default, but I was not sure if you created a custom one, because you did not mention how you were planning to have the cell rendered.  Try displaying an item outside the JTable in a JLable or something to verify path and resources are correct.